Cant change the output framerate from 24
Working on a project and as usual wanted to render the animation in 30fps but at some point, not sure what I did, the frame rate changed to 24 and I cannot change it back to any other frame rate.
Tried rendering it out, maybe it was just a visual glitch, but it still rendered out in 24 FPS.
The weird thing is, that project files made before I noticed the problem, have no problems with changing the framerate, and every new file I open has the same problem with not being able to change the frame rate.
Another quirk to this problem I noticed is my keyframes for world rotation, for example, are getting deleted at random points.
Here is a link for 2 blend files: Test Scene - A completely new file with nothing changed / Blowing In Wind - The scene I was working on.
WeTransfer Download Link
I appreciate if you take your time to investigate my issue, if there is anything else you need to help with, please let me know.
Edit: Blender version 4.1.1

Could you add your Blender version ?

That test file is fine here in both Blender 4.02 and 4.1.1 (which is the version you are using). The other file is over 300 Meg in size so I'm not downloading that one!

I tried both scenes, in both I was able to change the scene's frame rate.
However, to see the effect in the viewport, you need to set the playback to drop frames (or sync to audio, which drops frames):

Without this, the viewport renders every frame as fast as it can until it reaches the frame rate. Which works when you have enough performance to do so, but not if your scene is too laggy.
However, this will break live physics simulations. If you need to live preview particles, you need to play every frame, until they are baked. Once it is baked, there should be no problem with dropping frames.
As for rendering, you set your output to an image sequence. Image sequences don't have a frame rate. That's up to your image sequence viewer or video editing software.

The PNG sequence not having a framerate completely went over my head, that should be the solution to my problem, thank you for your help. The frame rate not changing on the dropdown many in the output properties is still a weird one, I will keep looking for a fix to that.

"The frame rate not changing on the dropdown many in the output properties" what do you mean by that exactly?
